# add private Nuget feed to Jenkins in .net core

Tags: c#, jenkins, .net-core

I have created Nuget package inside my private feed.

I have a .net core project.

How do i tell Jenkins to search for the package in my private Nuget feed URL ?

Can i set the feed URL inside the CSPROJ without specific Jenkins command ?

Comment: @KirkLarkin How do i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do via the `NuGet.config` file in your project, solution, or computer:

```xml
<packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="OtherSource" value="D:\Other" />
</packageSources>
```

See [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior).

Comment: do i need to add the Nuget.config to my project (csproj) ? or will the msbuild finds it ?

Comment: You don't need to add it to your csproj file, but it does need to be stored in your project. Possibly right next to the csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft you can configure your Nuget Sources in multiple places

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior

Then when your project is building in Jenkins it will refer these locations to get the Nuget package source